# ASPxGridView doesn't show the values which are coming from DataTable

Tags: datatable, aspxgridview

I have two gridviews on my page. What I'm trying to do is that copying selected rows in the first gridview to the second gridview.

It adds the rows without values with the code below. Why aren't values copied?

[image: Rows are added WITHOUT values!]

**C# code:**

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("siteName", typeof(String));
table.Columns.Add("siteIP", typeof(String));

List<object> fieldValues = gridSiteList.GetSelectedFieldValues(new string[] { "siteName", "siteIP" });
foreach (object[] item in fieldValues)
{
    table.Rows.Add(item[0].ToString(), item[1].ToString());
}

gridReadyToGo.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
gridReadyToGo.DataBind();
```

**ASPX code:**

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gridSiteList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" KeyFieldName="siteName" Width="320px">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowSelectCheckbox="True" VisibleIndex="0" Width="40px">
        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="siteName" VisibleIndex="1" Width="135px" Caption="Name">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="siteIP" VisibleIndex="2" Width="135px" Caption="IP">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    </Columns>
    <settingsbehavior allowsort="False" />
    <settings showhorizontalscrollbar="True" showfilterrow="True" />
    <border borderstyle="Solid" borderwidth="1px"></border>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gridReadyToGo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="siteName" OnDataBinding="gridReadyToGo_DataBinding" Width="320px">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowSelectCheckbox="True" VisibleIndex="0" Width="40px">
            <clearfilterbutton visible="True">
            </clearfilterbutton>
        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Name" VisibleIndex="1" Width="135px">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="IP" VisibleIndex="2" Width="135px">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    </Columns>
    <settingsbehavior allowsort="False" />
    <settings showfilterrow="True" showhorizontalscrollbar="True" />
    <border borderstyle="Solid" borderwidth="1px"></border>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Comment: try put a breakpoint before your loop, and let see what does fieldValues contains?

Comment: fieldValues contains the data that has been selected in the first GridView. Furthermore, After binding second GridView, I get the values manually from it and I see that values are definetely stored in GridView successfuly. They just don't show up for some reason

Comment: I have a similar problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: I couldn't find a solution. I used ListView instead of GridView in the right part